# Where can I shrink database directly from Central admin (SharePoint2010)

Tags: 2010

Where can I shrink database directly from Central admin (SharePoint2010)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't shrink your database directly from the central administration UI.

You need to use SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) to shrink your database.

I found a nice automated solution (SQL script) to shrink all your Sharepoint related DBs:
[Keeping your SHarepoint 2010 Development Databases small](http://blog.hompus.nl/2010/06/22/keeping-your-sharepoint-2010-development-databases-small/)

```
USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @dbname SYSNAME
DECLARE @altercmd NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @shrinkcmd NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE [dbcursor] CURSOR FOR SELECT [name] FROM sysdatabases

OPEN [dbcursor]
FETCH NEXT FROM [dbcursor] INTO @dbname

WHILE
    @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF
        (SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(@dbname, 'RECOVERY')) != 'SIMPLE'
        AND
        @dbname != 'tempdb'
    BEGIN
        SET @altercmd = 'ALTER DATABASE "' + @dbname
                                               + '" SET RECOVERY SIMPLE'
        EXEC (@altercmd)

        SET @shrinkcmd = 'DBCC SHRINKDATABASE ("' + @dbname + '")'
        EXEC (@shrinkcmd)

        PRINT @dbname
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM [dbcursor] INTO @dbname
END

CLOSE [dbcursor]
DEALLOCATE [dbcursor]
```

A different shorter method is explained here: [Sharepoint: shrink database on a fast way](http://blogs.technet.com/b/patrick_heyde/archive/2009/04/24/sharepoint-shrink-database.aspx)

```
USE MyDatabase

GO

BACKUP LOG MyDatabase WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY

GO

DBCC SHRINKFILE (MyDatabase_log, 1)

GO
```

Comment: @moontear: Generally you can reproduce content here as long as you follow licenses. For example, Stack Overflow require you give attribution if the content was originally posted there. A link to the original content will be fine in most cases. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can't...
You need to do that in the SQL Mgmt Studio. 
Here is a WhitePaper about DB Management in SharePoint, its also about shrinking DBs.
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=178357&clcid=0x409